# Java org.w3c.dom : is there a Java parser library?

Tags: java, parsing, dom

I have a DOM `Document` (`org.w3c.dom`) but I need to be able to find elements by XPath and such. Which parser or library out there can provide this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

The end of the page even has an example on how to use XPath on a DOM document :

```
// parse the XML as a W3C Document
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File("/widgets.xml"));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/widgets/widget";
Node widgetNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already havea `Document` then you don't need a parsers, as the XML is already parsed.

There's the [`javax.xml.xpath` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) that provides XPath functionality.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html

HTH

Answer (score 0):

My preferred `xpath` library is [`jaxen`](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/). It's simple to use and powerful. Sample usage (exceptions deferred):

```
List<Node> matchingNodes = new DOMXPath("//myxpath").selectNodes(document);
```